# The standart tool box disseapeared on visual studio 2008 Sp1?

Tags: visual-studio-2008-sp1

I have had Visual Studio Team System 2008 and I have upgraded it to Visual Studio Team System 2008. But, after installation, the standard tool box have been diseapeard. How could I make it visible/enabled again to use the drag and drop feature of VS 2008.
Regards
BK

Comment: And, the common elements such as  <br/>
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) does not appear on its *.Cs file as like as the blue font color. It meant not recognized in Visual Studio to me. <br/>
Moreover, I have added with writing <asp:TextBox.... /> it appeared on *.aspx file. I have put the text box to the file but not with the drag and drop tool.
<br/>
I hope I could described my problems.
<br/>
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:
-Close Visual Studio
-Enter "Run" Cmd to intilize the Commander:
-Write this below:

devenv /ResetSkipPkgs

Enter !

That's all! :)

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're not running in debug mode, as that will certainly cause the toolbox to disappear and not support drag and drop.

Also, the toolbox won't be there if you're not looking at a file type that supports it or have a project open.

To show the toolbox in VS 2008 go to the View menu and select Toolbox or hit CTRL+Alt+X.

Comment: Sir,
-I don't look for the standard toolbox while I am running it on Debug mode.
-It is an existing standard Aspx page which I use to see the standard toolbox with.

-I can see HTML toolbox but not with the standart toolbox with full of asp.net objects in it.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Window menu, Reset Window Layout?